# Problem with Rxjs subscription in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem with subscription in Rxjs in Angular. 
I have component A and from her, I send data to the service on `shopCartChanged = new Subject<ProductModel[]>();` and my component B is subscribed to the `shopCartChanged`. The first time does not fork, but when to send a second time object this works pretty well and I get all object from my subscription.

This is my component A and method `addToShoppingList` from him I send data:

```
  addToShoppingList(product: ProductModel) {

        if (this.shop.setProductCart({...product})){
            this.messageService.add('Proizvod je dodat u korpu!!!');
        }    

    }
```

My service `ShopCartService` and `setProductCart` where I set a date to the `Subject`:

```
  setProductCart(product: ProductModel) {



        for (let i = 0; i < this.productCart.length; i++) {
            if (this.productCart[i].product_id == product.product_id) {
                this.productCart[i].numberOfProduct += product.numberOfProduct;

                this.shopCartChanged.next(this.productCart);
                return true;
            }

        }
        this.productCart.push(product);
        this.shopCartChanged.next(this.productCart);

        return true;

    }
```

My `Subject` in my service `ShopCartService`

```
 shopCartChanged = new Subject<ProductModel[]>();
```

My component B :

ngOnInit() {

```
this.subscription =   this.shopCartService.shopCartChanged.subscribe(
            (products: ProductModel[]) => {
                this.productCarts = products;
                localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(this.productCarts));
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Where do you subscribe to the shopCartChanged subject in your Component B ? in the constructor ? The ngOnInit method ?

Comment: I do on the ngOnInit()

Comment: is it possible that the Component B is created after Component A for any reason ?

Comment: Component A and B are in a separate module. 
For component, A is implemented lazy loading but component B is not.
Maby is it a problem?

Comment: if you need Subject to contain initial value you might want to use BehaviorSubject

Comment: return this.subject.asObservable(); put one method in service class. getMessage() { return this.subject.asObservable(); } and call this method in ngOnInit() of component. like this.service.getMessage().subscribe (data => {});

Comment: I don't know if this helps but `1: this.shopCartChanged.next(this.productCart);
                2: return true;` 2 happnes before 1

Comment: Is component B the header for a shopping site (with cart count displayed) and component A the product page? Also, when you say it is not initially working, do you mean that the header doesn't display the count until a new item is added?

Comment: @SInsansun have you tried using ``behaviorSubject`` ?

Comment: I found the problem. I do not have a problem with the RXJS, I have a problem with localStorage, in other piece of code I used I puled data form localStorage and I made the mistake.